# How to compare folder to string

Tags: bash, shell

How do I check if `$dir` equals `"string"`?

I'm trying this:

```
array=(/path/to/folders/*)

for dir in "${array[@]}"; do
  if["${dir}" == "/path/to/folders/subfolder"]; then
    do something...
  fi
done
```

Comment: Use [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) to syntax-check your shell code; in the case at hand, you'd see: `You need a space after the [ and before the ].`

Answer (score 3):

In shell, spaces are important.  Replace:

```
if["${dir}" == "/path/to/folders/subfolder"]; then
```

with:

```
if [ "${dir}" = "/path/to/folders/subfolder" ]; then
```

Notes:

1. In shell, `[` is the name of a command.  It should not be concatenated with other strings.
2. `]` is the required final argument to `[`.  It also  should not be concatenated with other strings.
3. Although bash accepts either `==` or `=`, `=` is the POSIX compatible operator for string equality inside `[...]`.

Answer (score 1):

Strange as it may seem, `[` is actually a *command*, also known as the `test` command.  Try:

```
type [
```

You get:

```
[ is a shell builtin
```

This is historical.  The syntax for an `if` statement is actually `if` *compound_list*, the brackets are not actually part of the `if` statement, although of course that is where they are commonly used.

One of the general principles of shell syntax is that tokens are separated by white-space.  Therefore, parameters to the `[` command have to be separated from it by whitespace, just as you need the space in `ls -l` (`ls-l` won't work).

In addition, the *final* (right-most) parameter of `[` must be `]`.  Again, white-space must separate this to make it a token on its own.

So:

```
if [ "$dir" == "/path/to/folders/subfolder" ]
```

In this example we are passing 4 parameters to the `[` command.

The `{ }` were superfluous, but they were not doing any harm if you enjoy typing `{ }`.

Answer (score 0):

Though

```
if [ "${dir}" = "/path/to/folders/subfolder" ]; then
```

in [[ this ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38493110/1620779) answers your question, I would suggest you to use

```
if [[ "${dir}" == "/path/to/folders/subfolder" ]]; then
```

instead because the `[[..]]` form supports regular expression match( with the `=~` operator). See this [[ article ]](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) for more details.